# How to use TextWatcher when user finished/paused typing?

Tags: android, retrofit, autocompletetextview, textwatcher

I'm confronted to an optimisation problem: I want to do a dynamic AutoCompleteTextView, so I implemented "TextWatcher" to my class. I want that each time user type and make a pause or finished typing, I launch my DB request to get him a list for Autocompletion, so my question is:

How can i know when user finished/paused typing in an AutoCompleteTextView ?

Actually, my code do a request each time user type a character. So for "Hello" it will send 4 request to my DB, but i need it to send an unique request with the complete world "Hello" when the user finished typing.

Is that possible ?

Here's a part of my actual code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {

public final static String CLUB_NAME = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.FAV_CLUB";

List<devaddict.footbarcom.modelPOJO.Object> list;
Button searching;
AutoCompleteTextView searchbar_club;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    searching = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonseek);
    searchbar_club = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchbar_club);

    searchbar_club.addTextChangedListener(this);
    searchbar_club.setThreshold(3);

}
```

And then, in the same "MainActivity" class, below i got theses:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {

    System.out.println("TEXT CHANGED BY onTextChanged");

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
  //System.out.println("TEXT CHANGED BY afterTextChanged");
}
```

I thought that "afterTextChanged" method would be what i actually wanted, but i don't see any difference between it and onTextChanged.

System.out are here only for tests.

Comment: are you looking to wait till the user enters first space after the first word has been typed?

Comment: This could be a great solution @Droidwala , but sometime user would just type an acronyme like "PSG".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**onTextChanged()** is the main method where you could write down your logic..
if you are willing to wait for user to type 2 or more words you could write your onTextChanged() method like below:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {

 if(count > 4){
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
               //write db insertion logic here...
        }},700);
   }
}
```

basically you wait for 700 msecs and then do some action to make sure that user might have stopped typing..

See if this helps!!

P.S: Ali's answer below using timer is also the correct approach to problem asked by OP

Comment: Ok i've tryed it and it don't solve my problem. What you gave me just give delay between all character Treatment.

For "Hello", it still run 5 times (Because user modifier text 5 times, one time / letter).

I need the user to write "Hello", and after a pause, launch my DB insertion.

But thanks for what you gave to me.

Comment: well.then you could increase the count value like **if(count > 4 or 5)**

Comment: @Addict Did you tried increasing the count? Normally, i use this in my App for getting autocomplete google places api and it works..And yeah that delay logic without count logic is worthless..

Comment: Yep i tryed but i don't even understand the meaning of "count", the doc is dark on this.

Comment: and once user hits first space after typing one word then value of count would become 0 and value of start would become 1

Comment: Great explenation thanks ! I will try to work with it and give feedback here.

Comment: No problem..just mark it as answer if it helps..Happy coding!! :)

Comment: Marked as answer, but for people who read this, know that both answers works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it using Kotlin and Coroutines:
First define a job for doing that in your Activity or Fragment, like this:

```
private var textChangeCountDownJob: Job = Job()
```

then add a text watcher like this:

```
editText.doAfterTextChanged {
            textChangeCountDownJob.cancel()
            textChangeCountDownJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(500) // for half a second delay, as an example
                search(it.toString()) // doing your logic here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            MainActivity.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    timer.cancel();
                    //do something

                }
            });
        }

    }, 1000);//after 1 second do whatever you want

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
  //System.out.println("TEXT CHANGED BY afterTextChanged");
}
```

Comment: This work like a charm, after my pause i get the Words that i need, but theres a problem. After the timer's pause, (1sec with your exemple) the timer crash. Any idea why ? Do you need logcat or something ?

Here one of a crash: [pastebinoflogcat](http://pastebin.com/FBqqXWyr)

It seems like the timer.cancer() caused it. But without it, i get the same result as @Droidwala, it just put time between results, but still give 5 results for "Hello" for example.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: This seems to work well, it reduce the number of request, and i reduce it more by comparing if the new text is similar to the old one.

@Droidwala solution do the samething, it work as well. So both are valide answers.